# how i make foreign key using migrations in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, foreign-keys, migration, cakephp-3.0, phinx

I have a table "products" and "intervals" table. In the table "products" I have a column called "intervals_id" need to create a foreign key to the id of the table "intervals".

I'm using it, but it's not working:

```
public function up() {    
   $refTable = $this->table('products');
   $refTable->addForeignKey('intervals_id', 'intervals', 'id');
   $refTable->save();    
}
```

I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What exactly is not working? "Not working" is a pretty poor explanation. See http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#working-with-foreign-keys

Answer (score 0):

Bind the both models

```
$this->Product->bindModel(
    [
        'belongsTo' => [
            'Interval' => [
                'foreignKey' => 'intervals_id',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    false
);
```